# Meaning of the .utf8 suffix in a LANG setting

Tags: unix, locale, codepages

If I set LANG as follows

export LANG=fr_CA.utf8

I believe this means use the rules for French, as spoken in Canada, for currency, time, date, collation etc, and the underlying codeset is utf8 (and not for instance an 8 bit ASCII variant).

Is this correct. If so - could someone point me to a definitive reference please so I can educate others in my company.

Answer (score 0):

More or less.

The user can set the locale for [categories](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locale-Categories.html) such as currency (`LC_MONETARY`), time, date (`LC_TIME`), collation (`LC_CTYPE`), etc. separately, overriding `LANG`. As for the locale names,
 they are not necessarily the same on all systems (may be influenced by `/etc/locale.gen` and what's installed in `/usr/share/locale`), but the provided [glibc locale names](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locale-Names.html)

> Most locale names follow XPG syntax and consist of up to four parts:
>
> ```
> language[_territory[.codeset]][@modifier]
> ```